# How to get the redirect url from deeplink in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, url, deep-linking

How to get the URL from the given redirect deeplink string?

For example, if I have a deeplink string as

```
myapp://open-browser/https://mydaily.dev/JOURNAL/home?id=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000&source=01&channel_id=HOME
```

I would like to get the return result as

```
https://mydaily.dev/JOURNAL/home?id=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000&source=01&channel_id=HOME
```

I tried several methods from Apple documentation
[Accessing the Parts of a URL](http:///https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url),
the closest one was to combine `path` and `query` like below screenshot

[image: Playground]

Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Comment: Your "redirect deeplink string" should be a valid URL. While it can be parsed as a URL, it's bogus, and you will have trouble to get your redirect.  For example, `/https://mydaily.dev/JOURNAL/home` will be treated as a path. You need your redirect URL in the query or in the fragment of the URL. So you need to fix this first, no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get your question, I think you want to get only the url starting from `https://`, please correct me.

If so I think I could remove the deeplink url scheme `myapp://` and the host `open-browser/` like

```
let url = "myapp://open-browser/https://mydaily.dev/JOURNAL/home?id=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000&source=01&channel_id=HOME"

let deeplinkBase = "myapp://open-browser/"
let newUrl = url.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: deeplinkBase, with: "")
```

Then you could use the `newUrl` as you like since we got the expected result now

```
https://mydaily.dev/JOURNAL/home?id=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000&source=01&channel_id=HOME
```

My example for the `deeplinkBase` string is hardcoded, but I guess you could use enums or any handlers for it later.